# How do I delete all Entities in all namespaces in GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, namespaces, google-cloud-datastore

Google App Engine allows to administrate the Datastore
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html

but there is no mention about namespaces, except default namespace.

I have alot of namespaces and now I want to delete all entities/namespaces in the Datastore. Is there simple way to do it?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin.html#Deleting_Entities_in_Bulk Surely?

Comment: @Jakob Bowyer: "Surely" what? Default namespace?

Comment: Do you need to do it just one time?

Comment: @systempuntoout: Probably no. I need it until I finish developing my app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this would qualify for simple, but...

You could use the [mapper api](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/07/introducing-mapper-api.html) to create functions that will iterate over entire collections, and you can get all the namespaces used via `db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM __namespace__")`

So assuming you have a function for mapping over all of your entitys [like this one](https://gist.github.com/881458) called `each()`. You could run the following in a task or locally with the help of [remote_api enabled console](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html) to delete everything.

```
for namespace in each(db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM __namespace__")):
    # set the namespace
    namespace_manager.set_namespace( namespace.namespace_name )
    # get all the kinds used in this namespace
    for kind in each(db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM __kind__")):
        # get entity 'keys only'
        for key in each(db.GqlQuery("SELECT __key__ FROM %s" % kind.kind_name)):
            db.delete(key)
```

Comment: Batching deletes would improve the delete time. `db.delete(keys)`